# Rails 3.2 model constructor with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model

My model constructor:
**3.2:**

```
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super # must allow the active record to initialize!
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end
```

**4.0.4:**

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

How do I change the 3.2 constructor for 4.0.4 compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting this error when you try to create a new user from your User controller?

If you have code like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Then this won't work because you can no longer do mass assignments in Rails 4.

Instead you need to whitelist the parameters in the controller something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    ...
  end
  ...

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :email)   # etc. according to your user model
  end
end
```

Having said this, I'm not sure why you need the constructor in your model at all?  The initialize method you get from inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` should be enough.  But in any event you **will** need to whitelist the parameters in your controller to avoid the `ForbiddenAttributesError` error.

Comment: I deleted the constructor and it works. I also put the code in again and it works again. I think you are right and the problem was the mass assignments. Thanks